# Load Short&Long Tool Data from JSON in TradingView

Tags: json, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have test results generated by MQL5 Strategy Tester. This data is in JSON format. Is there a way to examine this data by creating a Short/Long tool in TradingView with Pinescript?

Example Data:

```
{"Open Time":"2023.01.04 09:00:00","Symbol":"GBPUSD","Type":"LONG","Price":1.19865,"SL":1.19758,"TP":1.1997}
```

I will probably need to embed JSON data into the script. Because I couldn't find anything about reading files outside of TradinView with PineScript. Is there a way I can at least create the Long/Short tool and change its values?

Comment: You can pass json with `input.text_area()` function, and then parse it with `str.*()` functions, e.g. `str.match()`.